# Is it possible to get the columns of few tables at once?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm interested in getting the structure of each table in my DB.
Currently I'm using: `DESCRIBE TABLE table1`.
However, this means I have to do a separate query for each table. Was wondering whether there is a query I can get the structure of several tables at once (and therefore saving me some queries)?

Thanks,
Nir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Account Usage/Information Schema view COLUMNS

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/columns.html

Following article have a slight difference example of using COLUMNS view to create a select statement but it should give you an idea

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Select-columns-based-on-condition-in-Snowflake-using-Information-Schema-and-Stored-Procedure

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options:

1. you can use the COLUMNS view in the information schema

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema/columns.html

Note:  The view only displays objects for which the current role for the session has been granted access privileges.

2. you can use the COLUMNS view in the account_usage share schema:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/columns.html

Note:  this will show all the columns in all tables, will show deleted objects and such as well.
Also note, there is a delay in the data (latency could be as much as 90 minutes, typically isn't though)